# Representing observations as a dictionary and filtering based on one key and value set

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a data set (in a file) composed of multiple observations (rows) with various attributes (columns). For example:

```
AttrA   AttrB   AttrC
 1       12      'a'
 2       43      'd'
 3       23      'f'
 4       25      'z'
```

I put this data set into a python dictionary such that:

```
data = {'AttrA':[1,2,3,4],'AttrB':[12,43,23,25],'AttrC':['a','d','f','z']}
```

I would like to be able to filter the observations based on a criteria of one of the keys. For examples. Filter observations for AttrA >= 3, such that:

```
 AttrA   AttrB   AttrC
 3       23      'f'
 4       25      'z'
```

or

```
reducedData = {'AttrA':[3,4],'AttrB':[23,25],'AttrC':['f','z']}
```

It seems like you could do something like: `reduceddata = {(k,v) for k,v in data if (??)}`, but I'm not sure what goes after the if statement. Also, is the a dictionary the best data type to use for this example? It seems like it would be easier to filter if the data was in a nested list.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: A dictionary may fit, but I guess the keys should be the values of AttrA, and the values should be tuples (AttrB, AttrC). or something like that.

Comment: The question is: do you have an actual key? The way you describe it here, you have simple rows, without any meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the structure first:

```
table = [dict(zip(data.keys(), row)) for row in zip(*data.values())]
```

It'll look like this:

```
[{'AttrA': 1, 'AttrB': 12, 'AttrC': 'a'},
 {'AttrA': 2, 'AttrB': 43, 'AttrC': 'd'},
 {'AttrA': 3, 'AttrB': 23, 'AttrC': 'f'},
 {'AttrA': 4, 'AttrB': 25, 'AttrC': 'z'}]
```

Now, you can filter it exactly like you described:

```
[row for row in table if row['AttrA'] >= 3]
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in terms of memory, to storing N dictionaries (where N is the number of observations) versus N observations within one dictionary? Seems like you would carry (N-1) extra keys. Thanks!

Comment: @user877334: It'll take up more space, but it's easier to query. You might want to consider using a database like SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_filter(data,attr,val):
    ind = [i for i,x in enumerate(data[attr]) if x >= val]
    reducedData  = {k: [v[i] for i in ind] for k,v in data.items()}
    return reducedData 

data = {'AttrA':[1,2,3,4],'AttrB':[12,43,23,25],'AttrC':['a','d','f','z']}

print my_filter(data, 'AttrA',3)
```

**output:**

```
{'AttrB': [23, 25], 'AttrC': ['f', 'z'], 'AttrA': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: @Ashwini: Thanks for the solution. I'm trying to understand the comprehension: 'reducedData = {k: [v[i] for i in ind] for k,v in data.items()}' From what I understand regarding comprehension the for loops start with the outer most and work their way in. It seems like in this case the first for loop is the inner loop and the second is the outer loop. Is this changed because of the brackets around '[v[i] for i in ind]'? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go with:

```
data = [(12, 'a'), (43, 'd'), (23, 'f'), (25, 'z')]
data_dic = dict(enumerate(data, 1))
reducedData = {k:v for k, v in data_dic if k >= 3}
```